# Laravel 4 : Does a master template get rendered before any replacement sections in the page template get processed?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a master template which has a section for breadcrumbs (using [davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs))

```
@yield('breadcrumbs',,Breadcrumbs::render())
```

In my departments.blade.php I then overwrite the breadcrumbs to dynamically load in my department names

```
@section('breadcrumbs')
    {{ Breadcrumbs::render($department) }}
@stop
```

I get the error

> ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/vhosts/test/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php) (View: /var/www/vhosts/test/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php)

Now what I'm not sure of is if this is a "feature" of laravel to render the master and then do replacements or whether this is something stupid I'm doing.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary comma in your 1st fragment of code. It should be `@yield('breadcrumbs', Breadcrumbs::render())`.

Comment: @kajetons now I feel dumb :), that being said it still doesn't render.

Comment: Also make sure `storage/views` are empty, not showing previous generated (wrong) view.